# What does granting all in database do?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried the below grants expecting it to grant read access to all future schemas and tables in the database `test`. This granted access to current tables but the future grant did not work.

```
grant usage on all schemas in database test to role dev;
grant usage on future schemas in database test to role dev;
grant select on all tables in database test to role dev;
grant select on future tables in database test to role dev;
```

I had to run the below in order to get future grants to work in schema dw

```
grant select on all tables in schema test.dw to role dev;
grant select on future tables in schema test.dw to role dev;
```

What did the first set of grants do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First grants should grant access to all new tables in any schema to role DEV. I tried to repro the problem:

```
create database test;
create role dev;

grant usage on all schemas in database test to role dev;
grant usage on future schemas in database test to role dev;
grant select on all tables in database test to role dev;
grant select on future tables in database test to role dev;

create schema test_schema;
create table test_table (name varchar);

show grants on schema test_schema;

+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|          created_on           | privilege | granted_on |       name       | granted_to | grantee_name | grant_option |  granted_by  |
+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2021-09-16 13:25:01.099 -0700 | OWNERSHIP | SCHEMA     | TEST.TEST_SCHEMA | ROLE       | ACCOUNTADMIN | true         | ACCOUNTADMIN |
| 2021-09-16 13:25:01.101 -0700 | USAGE     | SCHEMA     | TEST.TEST_SCHEMA | ROLE       | DEV          | false        | ACCOUNTADMIN |
+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+

show grants on table test_table;

+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|          created_on           | privilege | granted_on |            name             | granted_to | grantee_name | grant_option |  granted_by  |
+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2021-09-16 13:25:02.280 -0700 | OWNERSHIP | TABLE      | TEST.TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE | ROLE       | ACCOUNTADMIN | true         | ACCOUNTADMIN |
| 2021-09-16 13:25:02.337 -0700 | SELECT    | TABLE      | TEST.TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE | ROLE       | DEV          | false        | ACCOUNTADMIN |
+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

And as I see, it works as expected. Have you defined any other "future grants" on that schema (for any other roles)? When future grants are defined at both the database and schema level, the schema level grants take precedence over the database level grants, and the database level grants are ignored.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#considerations

Comment: I do have a future grant on schema level to another role. Because of that, future grant on database was ignored...I see. Thanks for explaining